# Suspected nginx client_max_body_size not working on 408 errors

Tags: reactjs, nginx, hapi.js

I have a Hapi.js, Node backend configured to accept files up to 20M from my React front end that works fine for uploading large files in development without NGINX.  When I include NGINX in production,  I get 408 errors in the browser and yet nothing in the NGINX error log.

As only files less than 1MB can be uploaded successfully, I assumed that the issue is with client_max_body size being at the default 1MB.  However no matter where I increase this (ie: http, server, location), it has no effect.  Here is my entire NGINX config.

I wonder if anyone else has experienced this, or has any idea why 408 errors are not showing up in the log?  I would really appreciate some help.

```
events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        sendfile                          on;
        tcp_nopush                        on;
        tcp_nodelay                       on;
        keepalive_timeout                 65;
        types_hash_max_size               2048;

        client_header_timeout             3m;
        client_body_timeout               3m;
        send_timeout                      3m;
        client_header_buffer_size         1k;
        large_client_header_buffers       4 4k;

        client_max_body_size              20M;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;


        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        server {
                listen 80 default_server;
                listen [::]:80 default_server;

                client_max_body_size 20M;

                server_name _;
                root /var/www/front;
                index index.html index.htm;

                location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
                        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                        expires -1;
                        client_max_body_size 20M;
                }

                location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
                        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        expires 1y;
                        access_log off;
                        add_header Cache-Control "public";
                        client_max_body_size 20M;
                }

                location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
                        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        client_max_body_size 20M;
                }

                location / {
                        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                        client_max_body_size 20M;
                }


                location /api {
                        proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                        proxy_pass http://my-ip-address:3000;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                        client_max_body_size 20M;

                        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
                        client_body_temp_path /var/nginx/client_body_temp;
                        proxy_connect_timeout 70;
                        proxy_send_timeout 90;
                        proxy_read_timeout 90;
                        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
                        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
                        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
                        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
                        proxy_temp_path /var/nginx/proxy_temp;
                }


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was having issues with the body size, nginx would give me a 413 error and I was able to fix it with client_max_body_size, so this may be something else.

According to the nginx docs, 408 errors can be returned due to settings in [client_body_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_timeout) or [client_header_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_header_timeout) but yours are already set to 3m so I don't know if that's applicable either. Maybe try setting those values crazy high to see if it helps?